# Issue With Sending Information From Form

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

EDIT: Solved the issue.  In the php code $q and $q2 did not get query.

```
$r1 = $db->query($q);
$r2 = $db->query($q2);
```

I'm trying to make a micro blog new feed for a class that I'm in and I am having difficulty sending information from a post to update the like and dislike buttons.  Below is the code for the post;

```
<form action="Assignment4_Main.php" method="post">
    <div class="newsFeed">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1"/>
        <a href="Assignment4_Profile.php"><?php echo $username?>
        </a>
        <input class="idr" name="postID" type="text" value=<?php echo $postID ?> />
        <p>
        <?php echo $text?>
        </p>
        <p>
        Posted: <?php echo $pTime?>
        </p>
        <input type="image" name="liked" src="Like_Not.png" alt="submit" width="20" height="20" value="1"/>
        <p>
        Likes: <?php echo $likes?>
        </p>
        <input type="image" name="disliked" src="Dislike_Not.png" alt="Dislike" width="20" height="20" value="1"/>
        <p>
            Dislikes: <?php echo $dislikes?>
        </p>
        <input type="image" name="reposted"  src="Repost_Not.png" alt="Repost"         width="20" height="20" value="1"/>
        </br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Also here is the php code;

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST["postID"])){
    $idPost = ($_POST["postID"]);

    $db = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "username");
    if ($db->connect_error) {
        die ("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    $gettingUser = "SELECT * FROM Post WHERE post_id = '$idPost';";
    $r = $db->query($gettingUser);
    $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
    $gotID = $row["user_id"];

    $r = $db->query($gettingUser);
    $row = $r->fetch_assoc();
    $gotLikes = $row["likes"];
    $gotLikes++;

    $q = "insert into Likes (user_that_like_id, post_id) values ('$gotID', '$idPost');";
    $q2 = "update Post set likes='$gotLikes' where post_id='$idPost';";
    header("Location: Assignment4_Main.php");
    $db->close();
    exit();
}
?>
```

As of now I think the issue is there is nothing being sent in the `POST` variable because if I put an echo after the first if nothing appears to happen.  Where I'm trying to send postID so that I can update the likes and dislikes on the server.

Comment: Is your `$postID` in input set? Did you check? If so, it should work because I have tested it seems to be working.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I not sure exactly what you mean by "set", but the  $postID is a integer number that is extracted from my post table and is placed there to make it easier to grab.  Therefore, each post will have a different ID.

Comment: Okey, let's say it's set. How exactly do you check if `if(isset($_POST["postID"])){` line is true? Because you said: "if I put an echo after the first if nothing appears to happen"

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas what I do is I use echos to debug where each echo has a different word so that I can follow what the code is doing.  In this case nothing is echoed back which I've learnt from debugging the other pages that either that the bug is above the missing echo statement or if nothing is echoed back means the code executed as intended.  But, since the "likes" were not updated and none of my echos where displaying lead me to the assumption that nothing was being sent and therefore my code was not executing.

Comment: So, you're writing something like `echo $_POST["postID"];`? You need to write `exit;` after it as well or you might not notice you echoed something.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas good to know, but the echos are more along the lines of echo "hi ", echo "too " ect.  I use echo $variableName when I think I've narrowed down the bug and now I need to know whats actually in the variable.

Comment: You can try writing `var_dump($_POST); exit;` to see what you're getting from the form.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I've found the issue, I forgot to query the database for $q and $q2.